# Magento Upgrade to 1.6 issue in bestseller products

Tags: magento

I have upgraded my Magento from 1.4 to 1.6

I have also installed a bestseller extension which is working fine on 1.4 and it is also working fine on a new instance of 1.6. but my issue is it is not working on the one i upgraded from 1.4 to 1.6

My code is like

```
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       // ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description')) 
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setPageSize(4)
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->load(true);
```

I keep the ->load(true) to check the query and i the query is

```
SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`short_description` FROM `tp_sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` INNER JOIN `tp_sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'cancelled' LEFT JOIN `tp_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc LIMIT 4
```

what i found is it adds the addAttributeToSelect fields to query list which results into error.

while the same steps new instance of 1.6 is not including those fields into query , it just adds those fields in the collection.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks